# Compile an .asm file through c# using cmd

Tags: c#, cmd, masm

I want to compile an .asm file placed in bin folder in the masm through c#.I have tried multiple methods like process.start but nothing helps.It opens the cmd but the command "ml" never executes.It either open the pwb.exe(MASM) or the 'file.asm' in notepad.I give these arguments to CMD **"path\ml file.asm"** which works fine manually.**ml is a command used to compile .asm files**. One of the method I used is following

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "C:\Users\Hassan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FYP\FYP\MASM611\BIN\ml file.asm";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start the process in this way, you'll need to put quotes round the path, due to the spaces:

```
startInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Users\Hassan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FYP\FYP\MASM611\BIN\ml"" file.asm";
```

(In a verbatim string literal, you include double-quotes by doubling them.)

Alternatively, if `ml` is actually an executable (I know nothing about masm) you could just use:

```
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Hassan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FYP\FYP\MASM611\BIN\ml.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "file.asm";
```

Comment: now it is working but i am getting this error "error A1000 cannot open file" some sort of restrictions? .... Running as administrator didn,t help.but if i go to the path first manually using cd command and then compile,then it executes succesfully.How can i fix this.

Comment: @user1904645: Try setting the working directory in the `startInfo`

Answer (score 0):

To start "cmd.exe" and run another program you need to use the `/c` switch.

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

So you would need:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/c \"C:\Users\Hassan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FYP\FYP\MASM611\BIN\ml.exe\" file.asm";
```

I've added extra quotes for the space in the path.

If you don't need to run it via the command prompt - "cmd.exe" - then you can put the path to "ml.exe" in `FileName` and just pass the "file.ml" as the `Arguments`.

Comment: now it is working but i am getting this error "error A1000 cannot open file" some sort of restrictions? .... Running as administrator  didn,t help.but if i go to the path first manually using cd command and then compile,then it executes succesfully.How can i fix this.